# Is there a such thing as "standard error of random variable?"

Tags: random-variables, standard-deviation, standard-error

I am wondering if there is a such thing as "Standard Error" of a random variable? If so, is it simply just the standard deviation of the random variable?

Comment: The bounty is a bit unfortunate for such a short question. Anyway, “standard error” is mostly about a random sample, whereas a random variable would (in nice cases) have “standard deviation”

Answer (score 0):

As Benjamin Wang commented, the term "standard error" is usually reserved for random *samples* whose distribution is possibly unknown. Given $n$ independent sampled observations $o_1, \ldots, o_n$ with sample standard deviation $\sigma_o$, the sampled mean value $\bar{o}$ has a so-called "standard error on the mean" given by
$$ \sigma_{\bar{o}} = \frac{\sigma_{o}}{\sqrt{n}} $$
where $\sigma_o$ is the sample standard deviation. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) for further details.

For random variables, the appropriate term you are probably looking for is just the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation). This always exists for discrete random variables but may be undefined/infinite for continuous random variables. Classical examples where the standard deviation is undefined are the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) and the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) for $\alpha \in (1,2]$.